# Program made from visual studio unexpectedly shut down and restart the program

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Recently, I have running into a problem that program made from visual studio properly has nullptr that is unallocated or something. Then it shuts the program and amazingly restart the same program.

do our community members know what is going on to my program?

I have SDL check and security check both enabled

Comment: We have no clue. Recommend running under the debugger to determine the location of the exception.

Comment: actually, I know it has usage of nullptr. but what I don't understand is that the program restarts..

Comment: Hard to answer with the little info you provide. Please, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created an MFC project with default settings. Among those default settings is *Restart Manager Support* (see [How to: Add Restart Manager Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/how-to-add-restart-manager-support)):

> The restart manager adds support for your application if it unexpectedly closes or restarts.

Reference documentation for the Restart Manager can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/restart-manager-portal).

Comment: found it, appreciate that. CWinApp::InitInstance() has registered all aspect of restart manager support to program